# Multiple scheduled LocalNotification

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to make more than one scheduled LocalNotifications in objective-c ?

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [dateComponent setYear:2014];
    [dateComponent setMonth:6];
    [dateComponent setDay:28];
    [dateComponent setHour:10];
    [dateComponent setMinute:48];

    UIDatePicker *dp = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [dp setDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent]];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    [notification setAlertBody:@"Hello"];
    //[notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3]];
    [notification setFireDate:dp.date];
    [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.soundName = @"Song2.caf";
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;
    [application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
```

I tried to repeat this process but it didn't work it's just taking the last one I made so all what I can do is one scheduled LocalNotification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.

Use

```
[application scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

to set the notification instead of `setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]`, for each of your notification objects.

If you need to set a very large number of notifications, you can add all of them to the notifications array after they're initialised and set:

```
[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:notification1, notification2, notification3]];
```